# Struggling to get nth child with hover to work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Firstly I know nth child is not compilable in IE. So i will have to use jQuery or Selectivizr to make nth:child to work in IE (or is there any other way?).

Here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kncdM/. the 9th 10th and 11th UL tags have to be repositioned to prevent them from overflowing.

How do I go about doing this?

I have tried using jQuery to do this however it does not seem to work. I used the following code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("ul:nth-child(9) li:hover ul").addClass("nth-child9");
});
```

with adding the following CSS:

```
#menu .nth-child9
top: initial; 
bottom: -60px;
```

Could someone please shed some light on how to get the following code working in IE please. Thank You

Comment: `:hover` doesn't make sense in a jquery selector.

Comment: how should i go about working around this?

Comment: that depends on what you wanted that to do.

Comment: Semantically, it makes more sense to give the nth-child(9) a class on load, and write your CSS accordingly. This also does away with the need for attaching a function to the hover event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul:nth-child(9) li').on('hover', 'ul', function() {
   $(this).addClass("nth-child9");
});
```

But, if all you're doing is adding two style declarations, why not just use CSS?

```
ul:nth-child(9) li:hover ul {
    top: initial; 
    bottom: -60px;
}
```

Comment: CSS does the trick however nth child does not work in IE. I have read you can use jqeury to load the class and this works with IE. Am i correct in believing this?

Comment: @rlemon .get() returns the dom node itself or a dom collection, not a jquery object, therefore .find( wouldn't work. I think you mean .eq()

Comment: Nth-child is supported as of IE9.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but got revived by an edit by marc_s (cleaning up spelling and such). I'll still provide an answer because it is a Q&A site after all.

As I said in the comments, it makes much more sense to add a class to the nth-child on load, and then write your CSS accordingly. Semantically this is straightforward, and it allows you to only write a single addClass function rather than attach an event handler.

jQuery

```
$("ul:nth-child(9)").addClass("nth-child9");
```

CSS

```
ul.nth-child9 li:hover ul {
    top: initial; 
    bottom: -60px;
}
```